# Filter text files from source code by filetype in linux

Tags: linux, file, text, grep, find

I have a list of raw files that were scraped and it consists of both text and source codes. Below is the filetypes listed and I wanted to remove all files which are of type C Source, python script, HTML and empty files and only keep ASCII and unicode files in place.

```
file *
1dW6WJMN.txt:  Python script, ASCII text executable
9dJbZ3Vv.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
9dQsmVU4.txt:  Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable, with CRLF line terminators
A5hENB7D.txt:  C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
cidREdJG.txt:  UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
exhjw1gK.txt:  UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
iu7LPrqz.txt:  ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
LsDHarjD.txt:  ASCII text
nLABt1a6.txt:  C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
nqMDtVuz.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
nqPuYb23.txt:  UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
nQtzxhfQ.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
NQuLWwpt.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
nQXeJeED.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
nqXGv6ws.txt:  UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
nQxr4Hwi.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
nQxr4Hwii.txt: empty
VQjrxevh.txt:  HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
yfDEfn4L.txt:  C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
yydAEDRn.txt:  HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

I tried using a simple grep with ASCII but all the source code files also contain the term ASCII. Is there any other way to filter out these source code files as sometimes there are also PHP, javascript files which I wanted to get rid of. I'm quite new to linux and any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple answer: grep will not be able to do this, since you need to determine the file type from the file contents. Once you have a tool to determine the file type from the file contents then all you need to do is write a script to iterate over these files with their type descriptions to filter them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to expand on [Filter text files from source code by filetype in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677142/filter-text-files-from-source-code-by-filetype-in-linux/62690885#comment110847826_62677142) stated about using grep. I would find what the output from *file* is from my files.

```
find -type f -exec file {} \; | sed 's/^.*: //' | sort -u
```

if I grep for *text* I get something like this:

```
find -type f -exec file {} \; | sed 's/^.*: //' | sort -u | grep text

ASCII text
ASCII text, with no line terminators
ASCII text, with very long lines
ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
assembler source, ASCII text
a /usr/bin/env php script, ASCII text executable
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
C source, ASCII text
C++ source, ASCII text
C++ source, ASCII text, with very long lines
C++ source, ISO-8859 text
C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode text
C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
exported SGML document, ASCII text
GNU gettext message catalogue, ASCII text
GNU gettext message catalogue, UTF-8 Unicode text
HTML document, ASCII text
HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines
HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text
HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
PHP script, ASCII text
PHP script, ASCII text executable
PHP script, ASCII text, with very long lines
PHP script, ISO-8859 text
PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text
POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
UTF-8 Unicode text
UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
XML 1.0 document, ASCII text
```

... so I would just exclude maybe *source*, *script* and *document*

Comment: Thanks Tim. To exclude the source,scripts and document do you think I also have to read the file contents of each files and filter it based upon that or a simple filtering using the filetypes would do?

Comment: I think in your example you were looking for all "ASCII text" and probably not any of the "Unicode text" files, so something like `file * | grep "ASCII text" | grep -v -e "source," -e "script," -e "document,"`